# Contactform 7 - wpcf7_admin_after_additional_settings action is not working within Class

Tags: php, wordpress, oop, contact-form-7

I am getting one weird issue while developing the Contact form 7 extension using PHP oop concept.

`wpcf7_admin_after_additional_settings` action is not working while I put the function within class, If I put that action's function outside the class then its working fine.

My code is following.

```
<?php 

    // This function is working if you put outside the class
    function action_wpcf7_admin_after_additional_settings( $cf7pp_admin_after_additional_settings ) 
    { 
        echo "Outside the class";
    }
    class Cf7pe_Admin 
    {

        function __construct() 
        {
            add_filter( 'wpcf7_editor_panels',  array($this,'cf7pe_admin_editor_pannels') );                              
            add_action( 'wpcf7_admin_after_additional_settings',   array($this,'action_wpcf7_admin_after_additional_settings'), 10, 1 ); 

        }

        // This funciton is not working within class
        function action_wpcf7_admin_after_additional_settings( $cf7pp_admin_after_additional_settings ) 
        { 
            echo "Within class";
        }

        function cf7pe_admin_editor_pannels ( $panels ) 
        {   
            $new_page = array(
                    'Stripe' => array(
                            'title' => __( 'Paypal', 'contact-form-7' ),
                            'callback' => 'action_wpcf7_admin_after_additional_settings'
                    )
            );  
            $panels = array_merge($panels, $new_page);  
            return $panels; 
        }
    }

$cf7pe_admin = new Cf7pe_Admin();
```

Please give your suggestion what to do if inside class function make it working. Please give your valuable input for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. you missed `array($this,` in `'callback' =>`

```
class Cf7pe_Admin 
{   

    function __construct() 
    {
        add_filter( 'wpcf7_editor_panels',  array($this,'cf7pe_admin_editor_pannels') );                              
        add_action( 'wpcf7_admin_after_additional_settings',   array($this,'action_wpcf7_admin_after_additional_settings'), 10, 1 ); 
    }

    // This funciton is not working within class
    function action_wpcf7_admin_after_additional_settings( $cf7pp_admin_after_additional_settings ) 
    { 
        echo "Within class";
    }

    function cf7pe_admin_editor_pannels ( $panels ) 
    {   
        $new_page = array(
                'Stripe' => array(
                        'title' => __( 'Paypal', 'contact-form-7' ),
                        'callback' => array($this,'action_wpcf7_admin_after_additional_settings')
                )
        );  
        $panels = array_merge($panels, $new_page);  
        return $panels; 
    }
}

$cf7pe_admin = new Cf7pe_Admin();
```